# Android doze alarm window

Tags: android, android-doze

I want to update my app to Android 6 and i use the alarmanager to shedule my background service. For my service it is important to be woken up in a approximatly hour long window. It must wake up in that window so not once the device exits doze, but i dont care when it wakes up in the window.

I use .setWindow at the moment to set my alarm. What do I have to use when I want it to work with doze mode? There is no setWindowAndallowWhileIdle

And as far as I know, setting a window instead of a fixed time should be preferred especially while in doze mode

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Android has finally decided to be strict about battery optimizations and hence it is difficult to [bypass](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html#assessing_your_app) doze mode. The whole point is that you really shouldn't be doing any work on a device that has been stationary for hours and rather wait until a maintenance window (where jobs will start) or the user picks up their device.

For doing inexact or periodic work which, please explore [JobScheduler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler.html): that's literally what it is built for and offers you good variety in terms of scheduling [based on criteria like periodicity, metered/ unmetered network, charging etc].

They don't want us to do any work at all while dozing. So from what I can think of, your use-case of "once every hour" is only on best promise from now on. Schedule and 'hope'. Having said that, Android N has a more '[practical](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HBPQZEU_ofg)' (lenient) version of the doze mode where maintenance windows are quicker. You could test, my feeling is that it's not as gloomy as it sounds. The policy is fair: if a user shows the intent of interacting with the phone, they would trigger jobs.

ref
https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/diving-into-doze-mode-for-developers/

Comment: The whole point of my application is to log data while the user is not interacting with the device. So i need to wake up the device in doze mode. so i think its just bad that i have to set an exact alarm to ensure its happening in my window instead of just setting a window and giving the system way more possibilities to batch the alarms.

Comment: yes you are right, setting exact alarms [which are anyway not exact after 19] instead of window looks like the way to go for you.
"The whole point of my application is to log data while the user is not interacting with the device" - that is what android doesn't want anymore. Their argument is that battery drain should not happen on idly kept devices. Since the user has not been using the same.